# How to run ipynb files in pycharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Unable to run ipynb file in pycharm
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srxd4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKBex.png)

Jupyter Notebook has been installed
The MindSpore virtual environment has also been successfully configured and added to the conda environment in pycharm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwIM0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOKFi.png)